# Minimax gamestate

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax

I am trying to implement a minimax algorithm, I have the jist of the algorithm down but it seems I need to 'undo' moves at a certain point in the algorithm. I can not find where this should be. If anyone could tell me where and why, it would be appreciated.

```
private int minimax(Player[][] state, int r, int c, Player player) {
    if (getWinner(state, r, c) == player) return 10; //returns 10 if player is winner
    Player opponent = (player == Player.PLAYERX ? Player.PLAYERO : Player.PLAYERX);
    if (getWinner(state, r , c) == opponent) return -10; //returns -10 if opponent is winner

    if (getPlays(state, player) > getPlays(state, opponent)) state[r][c] = opponent; //Puts opponent in current spot if player has played more times than opponent
    else state[r][c] = player; //Puts player in current spot if opponent has played more times than player

    for (int column = 0; column < GRID_WIDTH; column++) {
        int row = top(state, column);
        if (row >= 0) {
            return minimax(state, row, column, player);
        }
    }
    return 0; //minimax will only ever return this if there are no plays left to be made, meaning that the scenario resulted in a draw
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the state when you make `hypothetical`, otherwise the "trial" disk remains in the actual `state`.

This

```
Player[][] hypothetical = state;
```

should be

```
Player[][] hypothetical = (Player[][])state.clone();
```

Alternatively you could use `state` instead of your `hypothetical`, but add a removal of the disk after the loop:

```
if (getPlays(state, player) > getPlays(state, opponent))
    state[r][c] = opponent; //Puts opponent in current spot if player has played more times than opponent
else
    state[r][c] = player; //Puts player in current spot if opponent has played more times than player
int best = -10;
for (int column = 0; column < GRID_WIDTH; column++) {
    int row = top(hypothetical, column);
    if (row >= 0) {
        int tmp = minimax(hypothetical, row, column, player);
        if (tmp > best) best = tmp;
    }
}
state[r][c] = null;
return best;
```

Comment: I have made this change but the AI utilizing the algorithim still seems to be underproforming. You added state[r][c] = null, what is the purpose of this if the algorithm should never reach this line if it runs correctly?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think in cases where only one element changes, a trail is more efficient: a stack with actions that must be carried out to undo the modification (in this case write the old player back to the grid).

Comment: @Ulsting I guess this is a Connect-4ish game? In the loop, you're returning `minimax(...)` the first time the play is valid even though other plays may be better.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, it is Connect-3. But minimax itself only ever stops running when it fulfills one of the first two if statements, meaning a winner has been determined, which is the end of that "path" or the board is filled resulting in a draw. So the return `minimax(...)` will only ever return 10 or -10, or 0 in the event of a draw. A win is a win and a loss is a loss, they are all equal otherwise.

Comment: @CommuSoft Could you possibly show what you mean in code?

Comment: @Ulsting I fixed your loop to pick the best possibility rather than taking the first one available.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, this does seem to make it proform better but now it is taking about 15 seconds to play one game of Connect 3. Is there a smart way to only let it go so deep, so to speak, so as not to take so long but still get hepful results.

Comment: @Ulsting You can improve upon this by adding a static position evaluator, i.e. a method that says how good is a position without actually playing it out to completion. This is the trickiest part of any non-trivial AI, though.